# Pass multiple values separately to decode base64 in Bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, base64

I have two Base64 encoded strings that I want to decode both and also place a dot (`.`) between the decoded ones.

I can pass them in two separate lines; but it seems that `base64 -d` ignores newline character and treats them as they are two parts of one string.

This is what I tried:

```sh
cat file.txt | base64 -d | paste -d. -s
```

But it failed and I lost the separation point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, in `base64` encoding, newlines are not significant. To be more precise, newlines in the output stream have to have been `base64`-encoded from the original input, just like the rest of the text. Any whitespace in the encoded stream is ignored by the decoder.

To accomplish what you want, you should decode each string separately and join them afterwards. For example, this could work if your file only contains the two lines you want to decode:

```
(
   head -1 file.txt | base64 -d
   echo -n .
   tail -1 file.txt | base64 -d
) > out
```

Here you may still have to adjust newlines, e.g., if the original first line had its own newline already encoded and you don't want it in the output.

Comment: Ah, sad to hear this about base64! So, if I don't have an actual file for my lines (Actually I got my encoded strings from a bunch of piped `sed`s and `awk`s), I have to write them into disk, then reading and decoding in this way? Thanks, btw.

Comment: No, disk storage is not required: you can save them in variables and use `echo` to pipe them into `base64 -d`.